# Add text to TEdit like in TMemo Delphi

Tags: delphi, text, edit, memo

I need to add text from program to Edit01 like to memo01:

```
 memo1.Lines.Add(inttostr (b));
```

I have f as integer number and i need to add it to edit01.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TEdit` is single line editor and thus doesn't have `Lines` property, you have to use `Text` instead:

```
Edit01.Text := IntToStr(f);
```